# Add class to body depending on the content of meta tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for my English but I think its pretty easy to understand.

I use different languages on a website. I want to add a class to the body when the German language is selected.

```
<meta http-equiv="language" content="DE">
```

Tried this, but seems like its making no effect:

```
   $(function() {
            if  ($("meta[http-equiv='language']").attr("content") === "DE")) {
                $("body").addClass("german");
            }
    });
```

Comment: Right, what have you tried so far?

Comment: why you have to use `$(function()` ? Can you provide also your html?

Comment: if your code isn't working, try putting a `console.log('here');` inside the if statement to see if the selector is getting the language attribute value correctly. like on [this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/qarel/1/) there is also too many `)` in your code, see the below answer it was updated

Answer (score 0):

```
if(jQuery('meta[http-equiv="language"]').attr('content') === 'DE'){
    jQuery('body').addClass(yourclass);
}
```

Comment: might be better seleting the meta tag with the attribute of `http-equiv` rather then searching them all

Comment: @atmd I just saw that Mark add that, I wanna update my answer.

Comment: @LShetty I dont like that when you are editing your answer you cant see the question :P

Comment: I have edited with what Im trying with, and its not adding the class. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks guys!

Comment: There are too many closing `)` after the 'DE' so will get a JS error. Try `if(jQuery('meta[http-equiv="language"]').attr('content') === 'DE'){`

Comment: @JohnWhish nice catch. I removed the extra `)`